# bash.exe/ubuntu wsl in full screen mode windows10

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

How can we achieve this? I need to hide taskbar and also put `bash.exe` in full screen mode to have better view and focus.

Comment: What client are you using currently to access it?

Comment: What do you mean "client"? I install ubuntu in windows store and using `/system32/bash.exe` to run ubuntu wsl - I assume this is default behavior.

Answer (score 29):

Ok, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> works.

Comment: welcome to superuser; while this i guess works for you a fuller answer would help less skilled users. Do you have any source information that can be linked to, do you know if this is a default setup. again thankyou and welcome to superuser [Answer].

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand why you were downvoted, as you may have come across it without any reference. By the way... any ideas on how to disable the scrollbar?

Comment: @ezequiel-garzon: Yea, there's workaround solution here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/407#issuecomment-295761589